# Is there any terminating fold in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, exit, fold

I need some kind of fold which can terminate if I already have the data I want.

For example I need to find first 3 numbers which are greater than 5. I decided to use Either for termination and my code looks like this:

```
    terminatingFold :: ([b] -> a -> Either [b] [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
    terminatingFold f l = reverse $ either id id $ fold [] l
      where fold acc [] = Right acc
            fold acc (x:xs) = f acc x >>= flip fold xs

    first3NumsGreater5 acc x =
      if length acc >= 3
        then Left acc
        else Right (if x > 5 then (x : acc) else acc)
```

Are there some more clever/generic approaches?

Comment: Given Haskell is lazily evaluated, you can terminate evaluation whenever you want by simply not reading more data: `take 3 . filter (> 5)`

Comment: Yes, I know but this function first3NumsGreater5 is just an oversimplification to illustrate a question, failure condition can be more complicated.

Comment: You can also use [`takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:takeWhile) or something

Answer (score 5):

The result of your function is a list, and it would be desirable if it were produced lazily, that is, extracting one item from the result should only require evaluating the input list up until the item is found there.

[Unfolds are under-appreciated](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/289423.289455) for these kinds of tasks. Instead of focusing on "consuming" the input list, let's think of it as a seed from which (paired with some internal accumulator) we can produce the result, element by element.

Let's define a `Seed` type that contains a generic accumulator paired with the as-yet unconsumed parts of the input:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
import Data.List (unfoldr)

data Seed acc input = Seed {acc :: acc, pending :: [input]}
```

Now let's reformulate `first3NumsGreater5` as a function that either produces the next output element from the `Seed`, of signals that there aren't any more elements:

```
type Counter = Int

first3NumsGreater5 :: Seed Counter Int -> Maybe (Int, Seed Counter Int)
first3NumsGreater5 (Seed {acc, pending})
  | acc >= 3 =
    Nothing
  | otherwise =
    case dropWhile (<= 5) pending of
      [] -> Nothing
      x : xs -> Just (x, Seed {acc = succ acc, pending = xs})
```

Now our main function can be written in terms of [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr):

```
unfoldFromList ::
  (Seed acc input -> Maybe (output, Seed acc input)) ->
  acc ->
  [input] ->
  [output]
unfoldFromList next acc pending = unfoldr next (Seed {acc, pending})
```

Putting it to work:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ unfoldFromList first3NumsGreater5 0 [0, 6, 2, 7, 9, 10, 11]
-- [6,7,9]
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach! Thanks!

Comment: I was also thinkering on `unfoldr` but i was checking the items of the `pending` one by one instead of using a `dropWhile` and consuming the `head` like you did. Since there is no `mempty` of `Int` s I did it by returning `[]` instead.. which raised the return type to `[[Int]]`.. hence needed a `concat . ` :)

Answer (score 3):

Normally an *early termination*-capable fold is `foldr` with the combining function which is non-strict in its second argument. But, its information flow is right-to-left (if any), while you want it left-to-right.

A possible solution is to make `foldr` function as a *left* fold, which can then be made to stop early:

```
foldlWhile :: Foldable t 
           => (a -> Bool) -> (r -> a -> r) -> r 
           -> t a -> r
foldlWhile t f a xs  =  foldr cons (\acc -> acc) xs a
  where
    cons x r acc | t x  =  r (f acc x) 
                 | otherwise  =  acc
```

You will need to tweak this for `t` to test the `acc` instead of `x`, to fit your purposes.

---

This function is `foldlWhile` from https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative, re-written a little. `foldl'Breaking` from there might fit the bill a bit better.

`foldr` with the lazy reducer function can express corecursion perfectly fine just like `unfoldr` does.

And your code is *already* lazy: `terminatingFold (\acc x -> Left acc) [1..]` => `[]`. That's why I'm not sure if this answer is "more clever", as you've requested.

---

*edit:* following a comment by @danidiaz, to make it properly lazy you'd have to code it as e.g.

```
first3above5 :: (Foldable t, Ord a, Num a) 
             => t a -> [a]
first3above5 xs  =  foldr cons (const []) xs 0
   where
   cons x r i | x > 5  =  if i==2 then [x]
                                  else x : r (i+1)
              | otherwise  =  r i
```

This can be generalized further by abstracting the test and the count.

Of course it's just reimplementing `take 3 . filter (> 5)`, but shows how to do it in general with `foldr`.

Comment: The original code is not as lazy as it could be, for example `print $ take 1 $ terminatingFold first3NumsGreater5 ([0, 6, 2] ++ undefined)` throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you took would have worked if you'd used `foldM`, the monadic version of `foldl`. With the `Either` monad, `foldM` would terminate on the `Left` result, so we could adapt your code to be:

```
import Control.Monad (foldM)

list :: [Int]
list = [7,1,8,2,9,3,10,4]

firstThreeMoreThanFive list = reverse $ either id id $ foldM folder [] list

folder :: [Int] -> Int -> Either [Int] [Int]
folder acc x | (length acc' == 3) = Left acc'
             | otherwise          = Right acc'

  where acc' = if (x > 5) then x:acc else acc
```